# Layouts for website 30% bigger. Could the problem be related to dpi?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, dpi

I created multiple layouts for a whole website with 150dpis. I sent the layout to the developer and when I got the site back it was horrible.

The fonts were very big. The images too. The sizes are 30% bigger than what I had designed.

A friend told me this was related to dpi. Now I have to redo the whole site so that the developer can redo his work.

Does anyone have a solution so I can automatically adapt the layout I created to the actual sizes?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  DPI/PPI settings are ignored by web browsers. It's irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the dimensions of the image/page in pixels. My guess as to what probably went wrong is that when you designed the web page, you were not viewing or designing your site at 100%.  Web browsers display raster images at the native screen resolution of the device they are being viewed on - at 100% generally, except where system zoom might be set in the computer's display settings.  You really need to speak to your web developer I think, as I can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: @BillyKerr Actually if you change the image resolution in Photoshop the font size for texts will change (if the unit is pt) and it could cause some confusion if a dev uses that value as a reference. Although it should have the opposite effect - with higher DPI the font size value gets smaller.

Comment: Yes @Luciano, that could be part of the problem, but it doesn't explain bigger images than expected.  The OP needs to speak to the web developer, as we're only guessing here, I think.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for repplying so fast. I checked and as you mentioned I did make a mistake and used pt instead of pixels for the fonts. I’ll talk further with the developer and will try to find out why the images are also so big.

Comment: Might be worthwhile noting here, I gave up using Photoshop for website mockups a while ago.  If you (and your developer) have a CC account, you should already have access to Adobe XD - it's pretty simple software and not too difficult to learn, or if you are on a Mac, you might consider using Sketch.

Comment: Hello! I started asking around for more information and found a developer who has experienced this problem for a while. 
He realized that the layouts are 30% bigger. So every new layout he simply reduces it in 30% and this solves his problem. 
This is interesting because I had the feeling that my layouts were between 20 and 30% bigger by comparing my layout X created.
The problem is, my developer uses CSS and needs the information of an open layout. Not just a jpeg.
Does anyone knows how do I scale everything (texts and images) down in Photoshop?

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks a lot for your sugestion. I have already started looking at Adobe XD but the thing is, I would need to redo the whole website. I'm sure will use it in the future, but right now I'm trying to solve this issue, since I can't tell my client that we will miss a deadline because Photoshop played a trick on us. But your opinion is much appretiated. Next time only Adobe XD.

Comment: @Mel - you should be able to just scale the image using Image > Image size - setting the size as a percentage - like 70%, enable resampling, but make sure to engage the link icon so that the resizing is to the same aspect ratio.  Text should resize with the image no problem - I just tried this, and 60pt text resizes to 42pt text.

Comment: @BillyKerr can you please tell if image resize works for multiple layers at the same time? Or I will need to do one by one? Like I mentioned, the developer will need each objetc info for the css so I can't use a jpeg. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it does.  Everything is resized when scaling the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no clear idea how to define stuff for web pages. You need to define all your work in pixels.

> The fonts were very big. The images too. The sizes are 30% bigger than what I had designed.

Here we have one example. You wanted to use PPI from 150 to 72 which would double the size, but you say the size is 30% bigger, not 100%.

Your friend is wrong in some sense. PPI is irrelevant for screens.

**On Photoshop you simply need to define your project in pixels.**

---

Appendix:

When you export something in Illustrator the problem is **Dialog Box of Doom**.

[image]

When you prepare a document in pixels, the assets need to be exported, at the native resolution. In this case, the native resolution assigned is... 72 PPI.

This 72 PPI are irrelevant... except for illustrator, so your friend is right if you were working in Illustrator.

Comment: if I see what you are saying we couldn't have a 30% increase in size, when we are talking about a 100% increase in dpis. 
But the thing is, I used pixels for my ruler. Only text I used points.
But meanwhile the problem remains that Photoshop is a lot of the mark regarding sizes. 
The developer told me to make a simple test. Upload a psd to dropbox and then open the file in the browser, full screen, with a 100%! And there it is, the bigger layout with huge images and text.
If I scale it down to 66% then everything looks fine (there it is the 30%).
Any idea how can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be designing your Photoshop document at the wrong resolution. Websites will be viewed on a screen, and standard screen resolution is 72ppi.

You should be able to scale it all proportionally by going Image > Image Size... and changing the resolution from 150 to 72ppi there.

---

SIDE NOTE: For the sake of semantics — DPI stands for Dots Per Inch and refers to the physical printing process. When designing for screens, resolution is measured in PPI, which stands for Pixels Per Inch.